# Way to start a console application with elevated privileges from a Custom Action in a Windows Installer Setup Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, setup-project, vdproj

The installation for my WPF App is very simple and works the way I want currently, however I want one cusom action to occur during uninstall, where it calls the executable/dll of a project in the same solution which is installed alongside the project output of the main app.

The console application I want it to call basically just uninstalls certain services as needed. The console application requires elevated privileges however and so far when it gets called during the uninstall it just fails because of this. Is there any way to change the vdproj file or the properties of the custom action in the custom action editor to get the result I want? I'm avoiding diving into WIX right now, since it's a lot.

Comment: Does that console application *always* need to run with elevated privileges? If so, can't you just specify that in its manifest when you build it?

Comment: @AdrianMole It's specificed in the manifest to require admin rights to start, but the installer is running it without those privileges, causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem wasn't admin privileges but rather that the program was simply using a wrong path for a config file for the service deinstallation process, which was only happening in certain cases. Just having the app require admin privileges in its manifest was enough.